Possible to use the 'comments' option to check if a line is commented?
I am looking for a way to check if a line is commented or not. It should not be a filetype specific but should be commonly usable for a lot of filetypes. Note that there are single-line and multi-line comments:
//

and
/*
 *
 */

are comment formats for C.
The following function works fine:
function IsLineCommented(lnum)
  return synIDtrans(synID(a:lnum, match(getline(a:lnum), '\S') + 1, 0)) == hlID('Comment')}
endfunction

But synID() is very slow and
syntax always needs to be on. So I really need to find another way.
The 'commentstring' and 'comments' options are available and locally defined
in a buffer according to a filetype plugin as follows:
c.vim:
setlocal commentstring&
setlocal comments=sO:*\ -,mO:*\ \ ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,:///,://

java.vim:
setlocal commentstring=//%s
setlocal comments& comments^=sO:*\ -,mO:*\ \ ,exO:*/

lua.vim:
setlocal commentstring=--\ %s
setlocal comments=:---,:--

html.vim:
setlocal commentstring=<!--%s-->
setlocal comments=s:<!--,m:\ \ \ \ ,e:-->

For single-line comment, the 'commentstring' can be used. And 's', 'm', and 'e' flags defined in the 'comments' option might be used for multi-line comment but I am not sure.
Do you know a way to handle the 'comments' option?


Tim Pope's commentary relies on commentstring. For comments, just take a look at the other commenting-related plugins. 2. You can't rely on either comments or commentstring to be set (properly or not) for the same reason you can't rely on syntax highlighting being on.

